# Puma not handling concurrent requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, puma

I'm writing a small Rails app based on http://www.beilabs.com/2013/05/02/redis-pub-sub-and-rails-4-streaming

```
initialize = ->

  start_listening()
  $("#send-button").click ->
    alert("clicked!")
  $.post "/messages/send",
    payload: $("#my_message").val()
    return
  return

start_listening = () ->
  source = new EventSource("/streams")
  source.addEventListener "message", ((e) ->
    console.log "Received " + e.data 
    return
  ), false
  source.addEventListener "open", ((e) ->
    console.log "Connection was opened."
    return
  ), false
  source.addEventListener "error", ((e) ->
   if e.readyState is EventSource.CLOSED
    console.log "Connection was closed."
   else
    console.log "Something else"
   return
  ), false
```

However, when I click the div, the request hangs, since Puma is still handing the streams request.

How can I make Puma handle these requests concurrently?